# Very basic: ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I struggle with very basic Angular stuff.
And I don't know exactly, what to search for.

Like this one:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3]">
    {{i}}
</div>
<hr/>
```

The output is (as expected): `<div>1</div>...<div>3</div><hr/>`

What I actually want is: `<div>1</div><hr/>  <div>2</div><hr/>  <div>3</div>` (no hr after 3)

So like: 1 | 2 | 3

How can I do that?

**Please note**: No hr after the last div.

**Please note**: I cannot put the hr-tag into the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Vivz answered you can just wrap it in a parent div. If for some reason you cannot however, you can use the `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` directive:

```
<div ng-repeat-start="i in [1,2,3]">
    {{i}}
</div>
<hr ng-repeat-end ng-if="!$last" />
```

Comment: Oh, that's nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to create a parent `div` wrapping the `div` and `hr` and also to hide the last `hr`, use a comparison check with `$last`

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3]">
    <div>{{i}}</div>
    <hr ng-if="!$last" />
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice. Does angular have something like Vue's `<template>` tag?

Comment: I am not familiar with vue but angular has the ability to include partial templates.

Comment: Ok. `<template>` is just a tag that gets removed after the rendering is done. Like `<template v-if="true"><b>Hello</b></template>` would render to `<b>Hello</b>`.

Comment: Interesting. To my best of knowledge I don't think angular have a functionality like this. But if it was there we could have used it here.

Comment: Thanks, it works (+1). I opted for devqons answer, because it didn't need an extra parent div.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your `ng-repeat` at a level higher. For example:

```
<span ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3]">
    <div>{{i}}</div>
    <hr/>
</span>
```

The result will be:

```
<span>
    <div>1</div>
    <hr/>
</span>
<span>
    <div>2</div>
    <hr/>
</span>
<span>
    <div>3</div>
    <hr/>
</span>
```

*Note: I used a span for the parenet, but you can use another HTML element, such as a div.*

Comment: There should be no hr after 3 (edited question). I cannot put the hr-tag into the div.

Answer (score 0):

nr-repeat is  directive in angular which can can used with html element or itself as a tag

```
<ng-repeat ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3]">
  <div>{{i}}</div>
  <hr ng-if="!$last" />
</ng-repeat>
```

Comment: Please add details on your solution

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But I don't like it, because it introduces a non-standard tag <ng-repeat>. Out of curiosity I just tried to do the same with <xyz ng-repeat ...></xyz> and it behaves just like the ng-repeat. This was to verify, that the tag name "ng-repeat" has no meaning. But, well, it works, it solves the task, so thank you.